# Convert Array Lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
array([['1;"Female";133;132;124;"118";"64.5";816932'],
       ['2;"Male";140;150;124;".";"72.5";1001121'],
       ['3;"Male";139;123;150;"143";"73.3";1038437'],
       ['4;"Male";133;129;128;"172";"68.8";965353'],
       ['5;"Female";137;132;134;"147";"65.0";951545'],
       ['6;"Female";99;90;110;"146";"69.0";928799'],
       ['7;"Female";138;136;131;"138";"64.5";991305']], dtype=object)
```

I would like to convert is to a dataframe with this columns

```
columns = ["Gender";"FSIQ";"VIQ";"PIQ";"Weight";"Height";"MRI_Count"]
```

**NB**: From the array list the separator of rows values is a semicolon (;).Help me organize it to a dataframe with column names and row values from array

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for new columns:

```
a = np.array([['1;"Female";133;132;124;"118";"64.5";816932'],
       ['2;"Male";140;150;124;".";"72.5";1001121'],
       ['3;"Male";139;123;150;"143";"73.3";1038437'],
       ['4;"Male";133;129;128;"172";"68.8";965353'],
       ['5;"Female";137;132;134;"147";"65.0";951545'],
       ['6;"Female";99;90;110;"146";"69.0";928799'],
       ['7;"Female";138;136;131;"138";"64.5";991305']], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(a)[0].str.split(';', expand=True)
df.columns = ['ID',"Gender","FSIQ","VIQ","PIQ","Weight","Height","MRI_Count"]
```

Last some data cleaning - removed traling `""` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and convert columns to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].str.strip('"')
c = ["ID", "FSIQ","VIQ","PIQ","Weight","Height","MRI_Count"]
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.strip('"'), errors='coerce'))
print (df)
  ID  Gender  FSIQ  VIQ  PIQ  Weight  Height  MRI_Count
0  1  Female   133  132  124   118.0    64.5     816932
1  2    Male   140  150  124     NaN    72.5    1001121
2  3    Male   139  123  150   143.0    73.3    1038437
3  4    Male   133  129  128   172.0    68.8     965353
4  5  Female   137  132  134   147.0    65.0     951545
5  6  Female    99   90  110   146.0    69.0     928799
6  7  Female   138  136  131   138.0    64.5     991305
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution would be to use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Just [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) each element in the array with a `\n` character:

```
from io import StringIO

# Setup
a = np.array([['1;"Female";133;132;124;"118";"64.5";816932'],
       ['2;"Male";140;150;124;".";"72.5";1001121'],
       ['3;"Male";139;123;150;"143";"73.3";1038437'],
       ['4;"Male";133;129;128;"172";"68.8";965353'],
       ['5;"Female";137;132;134;"147";"65.0";951545'],
       ['6;"Female";99;90;110;"146";"69.0";928799'],
       ['7;"Female";138;136;131;"138";"64.5";991305']])

columns = ["Gender", "FSIQ", "VIQ", "PIQ", "Weight", "Height", "MRI_Count"]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(a.ravel())), header=None,
                 sep=';', names=columns, na_values=['.'])
```

[out]

```
   Gender  FSIQ  VIQ  PIQ  Weight  Height  MRI_Count
1  Female   133  132  124   118.0    64.5     816932
2    Male   140  150  124     NaN    72.5    1001121
3    Male   139  123  150   143.0    73.3    1038437
4    Male   133  129  128   172.0    68.8     965353
5  Female   137  132  134   147.0    65.0     951545
6  Female    99   90  110   146.0    69.0     928799
7  Female   138  136  131   138.0    64.5     991305
```

---

`pandas` should do a pretty good job of interpreting dtypes

```
print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 7 entries, 1 to 7
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Gender     7 non-null      object 
 1   FSIQ       7 non-null      int64  
 2   VIQ        7 non-null      int64  
 3   PIQ        7 non-null      int64  
 4   Weight     6 non-null      float64
 5   Height     7 non-null      float64
 6   MRI_Count  7 non-null      int64  
dtypes: float64(2), int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 448.0+ bytes
```